# Permission denied for SQL Server CE on Win XP

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am getting a `"Permission denied"` exception when I connect to a `.sdf` file.

I am using this connection string.

```
connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf;Password='something';Mode = Read Only;Temp Path= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates);Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is work fine on Win 7 but when I run my app on Win XP it returns

> *Permission denied*

exception

I tried different address for temp file but it still failed.all of this options are true

1. The paths to the Database File exist on the xp machine
2. I have permission to create a temporary file in the given
   directory
3. I'm supplying the right password.

This problem happens just when data base connection string set to read only.i find some solution but i can't use them:

**solution 1:**

> Here is the scoop on this. When we move a SDF file from XP to Vista,
>   because of a change in the NLS Version we attempt to open the file in
>   read-write mode to rewrite the indexes if any exist. This happens only
>   on the first open on the move from XP to Vista. So a simple work
>   around for you is to temporarily change the file to read-write mode
>   open it on Vista and revert it back to read-only.

I can't use this solution because my application run from DVD.

**solution 2:**

> having 3 sdf files, one for XP/Server 2003 and one for Vista/Server
>   2008/Win7 and one for win 8

This is also awful,because i don't have free space on application DVD to do this.

any one have a good idea to solve this problem.

Comment: Unless you manipulate DataDirectory, the database will reside in Program Files folder, which is read only by default by normal users.

Comment: @ErikEJ:I try different  folder from other drive and ... but don't work

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to somewhere it can be written, and remove the *Read Only* property from the file. Connect to this file.

[`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) can be called with [`SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get a suitable location.

[`Path.GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) might also be useful in this regard.

Comment: for some reason i can't copy my database to destination PC,but do you know Sq-lite solve this problem?

Comment: @irsog You can [`open`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) a SQLite database in read-only mode with the [`SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html) flag, but whether this is suitable for your scenario will be up to you.

Comment: Confused here.  Is it SQLite or SQL Server CE?  These are 2 very different things.

Comment: @AngryHacker OP's question and my answer are about CE. OP's comment and my comment are about SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either have 2 copies of the database file on the DVD, one for XP/Server 2003, and one for Vista and later. Or copy the database to a writable location when the app is first launched. Same issue applies to SQL Server Compact 4.0

Comment: :as i said in my question my database size are about 1.5 GB and i cant have 2 copes of them because the size is limited,and second solution is also not work for me because my application run form DVD.

Comment: :do you know Sq-lite has the same problem or no?

Comment: I do not understand why the second solution does not Work, even if the app runs from a DVD, it can use data on the hard disk?? And I have no idea about sqlite

Comment: Second option:because my database size is 1.5 GB and this take about 5 ta 10 min to copy to destination PC from DVD.this is like an multimedia application and i don't allow to copy 1.5 GB data to destination PC

Comment: this is not economic,but how about ms-access?

Comment: I think you will run into x86/x64 hell, and MS-Access Jet engine cannot be privately deployed,

Comment: @ErikEJ ACE can't be, but JET is part of WDAC and comes with Windows. No deployment necessary. Except Windows.

Comment: @ta.speot.is i'm also agree with you,but ms assess is slow,i finally decided to use sqlite,it's faster and It doesn't have this problem