# Does SQL Compact Edition 4.0 Solve "Permission Denied" bug on different OS version

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I previously asked a question about [Permission denied for SQL Server CE on Different OS versions when connection string set to readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064441/permission-denied-for-sql-server-ce-on-win-xp) but it seems there is no answer
to my question and i think this is a kind of bug from Microsoft.

So according this:

> As reported [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/04/01/after-moving-the-database-from-one-platform-to-other-the-first-sqlceconnection-open-takes-more-time.aspx) by the SOL Compact team (sadly, not before April
>   1st (!) 2009), the run time needs to re-create indexes if a SDF file
>   has been moved from Vista/Server 2008 to XP/Server 2003. On read-only
>   media, this cannot happen, and you will get an obscure [Permission
>   denied error message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/72fcc4f2-6c2e-402c-8785-926ed7d50ca5/).

So i want to ask dose Microsoft solve this problem in newer version of SQL Compact Edition 4.0 ?